# Clipping the buffer end using ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, buffer

Is there a way to automate splitting a buffer at the end point of the line or point it is buffered from and add the step to the ModelBuilder model?

I am using arcmap 10.5 standard licence, so can't use the flat end option in the buffer tool.

I have a model which produces buffers from points along a line, it then dissolves the buffers to create one final buffer. I then cut the polygon accross at the end of the line to delete the geometry past this manually, as I am not interested in anything past this point. Is there a way to automate this and add it to the end of my ModelBuilder model?

[image: Buffer Pre Manual Split]

[image: Buffer Post Manual Split]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Titles should be a simple topical summary with multiple questions. Your graphics don't look like buffers. You should always state the exact software in use with every Question (tagging with an ancient version doesn't increase response rates).

Comment: Buffer line using flat ends option and use it to clip original.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without an advanced licence though? I only have a standard licence

Comment: This [tool](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=54ad502f798c4cc780a1132ad44670a9) might help? Not used it so can't comment on it.